# Modify a `byte[]` after it has been wrapped by a `MemoryStream` by performing actions on the stream?

Tags: c#, stream, arrays

Is it possible to modify a `byte[]` after it has been wrapped by a `MemoryStream`, by performing actions upon the stream?

I have a codebase which predominantly uses `byte[]` as opposed to `Stream`, and a 3rd party method that I want to use that acts upon a `Stream`.

I've played around in a sample solution, and with code like the below, we see that the `originalBytes` variable has not been modified, even though the stream clearly has.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string filePath = "C:\\new text document.txt";

        var originalBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

        var stream = new MemoryStream(originalBytes);

        stream.SetLength(1);

        var modifiedBytes = stream.ToArray();

        Console.WriteLine(originalBytes.Length == modifiedBytes.Length);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to associate a `byte[]` with a `MemoryStream` in such a way that a modification to the stream will also have an impact upon the array?

I am hamstrung by decisions that have been made in this solution which means that I don't have the simple option of refactoring the solution to use a stream more often around the codebase.

---

edit:
I see now that my snippet wasn't correct. Better to represent this would be something simple like

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const string filePath = "C:\\new text document.txt";

    var originalBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

    var stream = new MemoryStream(originalBytes);

    var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream);
    streamWriter.Write("54321");
    streamWriter.Flush();

    var modifiedBytes = stream.ToArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < originalBytes.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(originalBytes[i] == modifiedBytes[i]);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

which, while crude, does give some indication that the modified bytes and the original bytes are, in fact, representative of each other and hence the underlying bytes of `originalBytes` have been modified.

Comment: Could work, but this will generally fail when the other code tries to write past the end of the array.  MemoryStream will not resize the array for you.  If you want it safe then you should not use the MemoryStream(byte[]) constructor and use Write() instead to initialize it from your byte[].

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The sample was my understanding of performing some modification to the stream and then trying to see if the byte array before and after were similar, which wasn't well represented by the example, as you point as, as resizing array isn't safe.

The actual example method I want to call is based in encrypting some stream. I'm going to append a more accurate code snippet to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array passed into the memory stream with the [`MemoStream(byte[])` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e55f3s5k(v=vs.110).aspx) *will* be used as the backing buffer and it *does* reflect changes.

Do *not* call `MemoryStream#ToArray()` here, which always creates a *new* array. The length of this array is determined by how much data really exists within the memory stream (as written or adjusted by `SetLength`), independent of the internal buffer size. As shown this can be less than the originally supplied array length.

Do *not* call `MemoryStream#GetBuffer()` either, because that will throw an exception. Simply use - "remember" - the original array, as it represents the 'live buffer data'.

(The length of the original array cannot be changed because arrays have an immutable size; the 'length of relevant data' may need to be carried as a separate value somehow.)

Comment: I see now that the sample I was working with wasn't accurately representing a modification of the data. After modifying the sample application to use 

            `var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream);

            streamWriter.Write("some garbage");

            streamWriter.Flush();`
that the stream was modified. Thanks!